# JMeter - execute 100K requests (CSV driven) in parallel

Tags: jmeter

I have a task to execute 100K requests using CSV data driven

CSV holds ids

```
100,
101,
102,
...
```

In JMeter CSV Data Set Config is saving `id` variable and call API with ${id}

This is working fine, but I want to execute requests in parallel to **reduce time** of execution.

It seems that parallel sampler/controller can't be used in this case,

How can this be done using CSV driven test?

Comment: are you running with single thread? if yes, run with mutliple users.

Comment: @KaushlendraJha Nice comment, how many users should I use? can you answer?

Comment: It totally depends on how much user load your application can sustain. Try with 50 or 100 users and you can increase the load if you are not seeing any failures/issues.

Comment: @KaushlendraJha if you answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) set ["Sharing Mode"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) parameter to `All threads`.

   [image]
2. In the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) set "Number of Threads" to the desired value

   [image]
3. That's it, JMeter will run your requests in parallel and each thread (virtual user) will pick up new line from the CSV file on each iteration as it can be seen using i.e. [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener

   [image]

Comment: I am trying to achieve something same as above, but after configuring jmeter to simulate multiple users it has been observed that requests are being sent in a bunch of 5-10 thread instead of concurrent requests at once. @Dmitri T