# Delay between HTTP requests which is from a CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter. I have a thread group that pulls multiple parameters from a CSV file and makes HTTP requests. I want each request to have 3 seconds in between. I tried to use constant timer, but it sends one request and stops. How can I do this?

My CSV file has 8073 lines. Each line is one request.

This is what my thread group looks like:

```
Thread Group
    CSV Data Set Config
    HTTP Request
    Save Responses to a File
    View Results Tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want delay before each request - add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) like:

[image]

if you want delay after each request - add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler like:

[image]

---

With regards to your "sends one request and stops" behaviour, by default [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) makes only one "iteration":

[image]

you either need to change this `1` to `8073` or just tick "Infinite" box and configure [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to stop when it reaches the end of the CSV file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make the Thread Group Loop Count `Infinite` and CSV Data Set Config's Stop thread of EOF `true`, it'll execute all CSV records

See also option to [execute CSV rows in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427220/jmeter-execute-100k-requests-csv-driven-in-parallel)