# JMeter - Resume CSV driven execution while ignoring rows used

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm running in parallel  [CSV driven test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427220/jmeter-execute-100k-requests-csv-driven-in-parallel) and sometimes stop test immediately using `./shutdown.sh`, and it works as expected,

The issue I want to resume execution excluding CSV records/rows that already used/read

Is there a way to read CSV and mark records as executed so it will be ignored on resume/re-run?

Is my option to create and update a different file with the row numbers used and check in script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-behaved tests need to be [repeatable](https://www.ontestautomation.com/best-practice-focus-on-repeatability-of-your-automated-tests/) and ideally should leave the system in the same state as the before test, JMeter provides [setUp](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [tearDown](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) thread groups for implementing pre and post test logic. So maybe it worth re-considering the way of how test data is being used and achieve test repeatability instead?

---

Coming back to your question: when you run JMeter every time it's a different separate Java process which doesn't know anything about previous executions.

The easiest solution would be switching to [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which has `KEEP=FALSE` parameter so you will use the data only once or to [Redis DataSet Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/Using-Redis-Dataset-JMeter-Plugin) where you can also remove data which has been read.

---

A vanilla JMeter solution would be writing the data which has been used during the previous test into .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) or into a separate file using [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) so this data could be removed from the original CSV file before next execution.